# Can't get the value passed in any way to the entry index.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am learning redux with react and hit a mental roadblock, I have the following entry index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Main from './components/front/Main';
import Login from './components/front/Login';
import Home from './components/front/Home';
import Register from './components/front/Register';
import Forgot from './components/front/Forgot';
import Verify from './components/front/Verify';
import Dashboard from './components/back/Dashboard';
import './css/app.css';

import Auth from './components/Auth';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    Auth.isLogged ? ( //<-need to get props here
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)

const App = () => (<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    {/* PUBLIC */}
      <Route path={'/'} exact component={Home}/>
      <Route path={'/login'} component={Login}/>
      <Route path={'/register'} component={Register}/>
      <Route path={'/forgot'} component={Forgot}/>
      <Route path={'/verify'} component={Verify}/>

    {/* PRIVATE */}
      <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>

  </div>
</BrowserRouter>);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Overall redux works, the only problem is in this file, as I am not exporting anything, I can't get connect to work.

Ideally Auth.isLogged should be either true or false based on isAuthenticated prop, but I can't get the value passed in any way to the entry index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

@connect((store) => {
  return {isAuthenticated: store.auth.isAuthenticated, authenticating: store.auth.authenticating};
})

export default class Auth extends React.Component {
  //Can't get anything from here to index.js
}
```

Please any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is ‘isAuthenticated’ part of your app’s state? Can you access it via a selector?

Comment: Yes it is part of app's state. I'm not sure about selectors

Comment: Awesome man! Glad you were able to get it done. Would you mind marking the answer correct when you get a chance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you’re trying to provide context of `store.auth.isAuthenticated` to `PrivateRoute`.

If you declare App in its' own file you can `connect` it to the store and then pass the value of `isAutenticated` to your PrivateRoute component

```
//App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import PrivateRoute from 'components/PrivateRoute'

@withRouter
@connect(store => ({ 
  isAuthenticated: store.auth.isAuthenticated,
  authenticating: store.auth.authenticating
}))
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props

    return (
      <span>
        {/* PUBLIC */}
        { !isAuthenticated && 
          <Switch>
            <Route path={'/'} exact component={Home}/>
            <Route path={'/login'} component={Login}/>
            <Route path={'/register'} component={Register}/>
            <Route path={'/forgot'} component={Forgot}/>
            <Route path={'/verify'} component={Verify}/>
          </Switch>
         }

         {/* PRIVATE */}
         { isAuthenticated &&
           <PrivateRoute 
             isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
             path="/dashboard" 
             component={Dashboard}
           />
         }
       </span>        
    )       
  }
}

export default App
```

For readability sake you could make this change in `index.js`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

You may or may not need to wrap connect(App) inside of withRouter, but the way I was handling my routing made this part necessary.

Comment: Thanks! How are you calling App.js in index.js? "import App from './App'" gives a SyntaxError in the line where the class is defined in App.js

Comment: Can you show me what your folder structure looks like? It appears you have something like src/components and maybe a src/containers, and index lives outside in src/index.js? In this case since App is a smart component I would save it in src/containers and import it via './containers/App'

Comment: /assets/index.js
/assets/App.js
/assets/components/PrivateRoute.js

Comment: I would structure that a bit differently as the project grows. See the second image in this [article](https://daveceddia.com/react-project-structure/). But with the way you have it now you should just be able to `import App from './App'`

Comment: Are you sure App.js is complete? I added the import to every Component, but that's about it, it fails when trying to import it into index.js

Comment: I didn't actually run the file, so it may have a syntax error somewhere. Can you share a gist of those two files?

Comment: Yes there is a closing parenthesis ")" missing for connect. Now I get an unexpected token error in { !isAuthenticated at the "!"

Comment: Try { (!isAuthenticated) && ... }

Comment: I forgot to wrap the whole thing in an element so `return (<span>current code</span>)` or whichever element you prefer like a div

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160533/discussion-between-s-age-and-galgo).